# @RequestBody gives empty JsonObject when making a POST Request

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/write", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
Status writeBuildData(@RequestBody JsonObject templateDataJSON){}
```

Basically I make an Ajax `POST` request sending JSON, I always get an empty `JsonObject {}` as a result

```
JsonObject templateDataJSON = "{}";
```

But if I use String instead of `JsonObject`, I get the correct value.

This app is made with **Spring Mvc 4.1.4**.

Dependencies:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Any idea what I am missing and why the `JsonObject` doesn't get injected and always gives me `{}`?

Comment: `JsonObject` being Gson's class?

Comment: What is "the correct value"? Unless that's Groovy, you didn't actually post the method.

Comment: Yes, JsonObject is a Gson class. The correct value is any Json that is not empty. I always get an empty JsonObject.

Comment: This works fine for me. Note that Spring no longer supports Jackson 1. Please add your MVC configuration.

Comment: Jackson has a class called `JsonNode` which is the equivalent of `JsonObject`. That can be used without changing anything else

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring no longer supports Jackson 1 as a message converter implementation.

So your

```
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
```

is actually meaningless to Spring.

Your

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

will cause Spring to use `GsonHttpMessageConverter` and, basically, do

```
String json = "{\"random\":\"42\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
```

`JsonObject` is a Gson type. Gson is aware of it and knows how to deserialize JSON object json into it. This will work correctly and will generate a `JsonObject` which has a value of

```
{"random":"42"}
```

Since you're saying that you're getting an empty `JsonObject`, I can only assume that you have Jackson 2 on your classpath.

Spring registers the Jackson `HttpMessageConverter`, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, before the `GsonHttpMessageConverter` if both are present on the classpath.

With Jackson, Spring would have deserialized your request body basically as such

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
JsonObject jsonObject = mapper.readValue(json, JsonObject.class);
```

which you'll note results in

```
{}
```

This is because Jackson knows nothing about the type `JsonObject` so it has to dynamically build a deserialization strategy. That strategy depends on properties which Jackson defines as setters (for the context of deserialization) or anything annotated with `@JsonProperty`, which obviously `JsonObject` doesn't have. So it basically thinks the type `JsonObject` doesn't have any properties (or maybe none that appear in your custom JSON content). As such, and because it ignores any unknown properties (which would have caused it to throw exceptions), it simply returns a new, empty `JsonObject` object.

One solution is to remove Jackson 2 from the classpath. Another solution is to explicitly add `HttpMessageConverter` instances in the order you want.

Comment: Would it be possible to change ObjectMapper behavior to not ignore unknown values?

Comment: @Rafael Yeah, you can register a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` yourself where you initialize the `ObjectMapper` however you want it. With Spring Boot, this might be even easier by just declaring an `ObjectMapper` `@Bean`.

Answer (score 8):

The explanation why it fails is perfectly done at Sotirios Delimanolis answer.

However there is a workaround:

```
@RequestBody Map<String, String> json
```

That way you can continue using Jackson HttpMessageConverter and work with custom objects in payload.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> yourMethod(@RequestBody String data) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    //use the jsonObject now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What represents JsonObject ? You should use object that represent json you sending. Something like

```
public class Foo {
    String foo;
    String bar;
}
```

instead JsonObject

and json like :

```
{
  "foo" : "val",
  "bar" : "val"
}
```

Comment: JsonObject is the default class from Gson. I wanted to use it in order to avoid creating other classes for modelling.

Answer (score -2):

Have you defined a dedicated converter for it ?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody